# Is it meaningful to have 2 git repositories for one project?

Tags: git

Me and my brother are working on a game - I am coding, he is drawing. Thus the files are completely independent from each other. Would it be meaningful to have one repository for code, and one for images? I'm not too keen on using branches, because as much as I understood, we would have to merge them very often to test how it looks, and then branch off again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be fine with just a single repository.  You can use one folder containing the images and UI files and another folder for the code.  The exact Git workflow is up to you to choose, though using separate UI and code branches for each of you is one option.

> I'm not too keen on using branches, because as much as I understood, we would have to merge them very often to test how it looks, and then branch off again.

You may have to merge (or rebase) often to see how it looks, but since you and your brother are working on fairly different parts of the overall app, there should be little or no conflicts.  This means that when either one of you does a `git pull`, it should not be too much work.